# Not work id getter in model (i use uuid type)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I make the primary key as uuid in Model.

Migration with uuid primary key:

```
Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->unique()->primary();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestampsTz();
});
```

Checking model:

```
Psy Shell

>>> $x = App\Models\Brand::find('e025b8aa-c71e-42ca-b87c-7ee27695b83a');
=> App\Models\Brand {#720
  id: "e025b8aa-c71e-42ca-b87c-7ee27695b83a",
  title: "Batman",
  created_at: "2017-04-28 23:51:41+10",
  updated_at: "2017-04-28 23:51:41+10",
}
```

When accessing the model, it contains the correct data.

```
>>> $x->title
=> "Batman"
>>> $x->id
=> 0
```

Why zero?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UUID primary key in Eloquent model is stored as uuid but returns as 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805474/uuid-primary-key-in-eloquent-model-is-stored-as-uuid-but-returns-as-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent has some default conventions and thus has some expectations on your model, table, constraints etc...
Luckily, you can change them:

[From the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions):

> Primary Keys
>
> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column
>   named id. You may define a $primaryKey property to override this
>   convention.
>
> In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing
>   integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be
>   cast to an int automatically. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or
>   a non-numeric primary key you must set the public $incrementing
>   property on your model to false.

Regarding your question: "Why zero?"

Because Eloquent casts the string of `"e025b8aa-c71e-42ca-b87c-7ee27695b83a"` explicitly to an int value and that result is int `0`...