# uri segment laravel not working for string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my database, primary key has string and number likes
ex : BRG2289182

My Controller

```
public function edit(BarangModel $barang)
{
    return view('fbarangs.edit',compact('barang'));
}
```

My Model

```
class BarangModel extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'barang_kode',
        'barang_nama',
        'barang_jenis',
        'barang_hbeli',
        'barang_hjual',
        'barang_stok',
    ];

    protected $table = 'barangs';
    protected $primaryKey = 'barang_kode';
}
```

My routes

```
Route::resource('barangs','BarangController');
```

my link

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" 
  href="{{ route('barangs.edit',$barang->barang_kode) }}">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> 
</a>
```

I want to do routing for view, edit, delete. in my database, there is one primary key field that uses a mixture of letters and numbers.
and the problem is when I use it for routing why can't it?
but when I change the primary key data to a number, the result is successful. can anyone help me?

answer :
add this code on my model

```
public $incrementing = false
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `protected $incrementing = false` on the model?

Comment: it seems that I haven't used the code yet.

Answer (score 0):

based on  @Travis Britz comments
I get a solution that I have to add a some line at my model

```
protected $incrementing = false
```

on my case i need to change protected to public so the answer is

```
public $incrementing = false
```

and this working fine now

Comment: My mistake, you're right that the property is `public`. Without this, Laravel assumes that it's an incrementing *integer*, and casts your string to an int (probably `0`). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691024/6038111